# Outlook Add-In Development in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I am currently trying to write an Add-In for outlook that displays a message box if an email is from an external address(outside of my company).

I am new to this so I am trying to take babysteps, but I have hit a wall. In my head, this should be working, but nothing appears.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;

    private string getSenderEmailAddress(Outlook.MailItem mail)
    {
        Outlook.AddressEntry sender = mail.Sender;
        string SenderEmailAddress = "";

        if (sender.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry || sender.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
        {
            Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = sender.GetExchangeUser();
            if (exchUser != null)
            {
                SenderEmailAddress = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SenderEmailAddress = mail.SenderEmailAddress;
        }

        return SenderEmailAddress;
    }

    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (mailItem != null)
        {

            if(getSenderEmailAddress(mailItem).Contains("@gmail.com"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("From an external email");
            }

        }
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This seems to be doing nothing. I need it to check whatever email is open and displayed on my screen. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug the code? Is the `NewInspector` event handler invoked at all?

Anyway, the `NewInspector` event handler is not the right place for accessing Outlook items. A fake item can be provided because the inspector at this stage didn't load the item fully. So, I'd recommend waiting for the first `Activate` event of the Inspector class and access the item then.

Also you may find inspector wrappers helpful. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How to: Implement a Wrapper for Inspectors and Track Item-Level Events in Each Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184620.aspx)
- [Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Outlook 2010: Developing an Inspector Wrapper](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Outlook-2010-Developing-an-c4470591)

Comment: As far as debugging goes, I get a notification that says it cannot preview it.

However, with how the code is currently; the message box will display if I double click on the email and open it that way. Is there a way for the code to read the sender info of the message when you just single click on it and read it within the main outlook page itself, rather than opening the mail in it's own window?

Comment: You need to handle the `SelectionChange` event of the `Explorer` class and track the `Selection` object based on which you can get the sender information. See [How to: Programmatically Determine the Current Outlook Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Using the Explorer class worked wonders! I'm now getting an effect close to what is desired!

A follow up question would be, do you know of a way I can display a warning text below the sender address in the email preview without flagging the email?

Comment: You may consider creating an adjoining form region for that.